Curve Fit for interpolated data
I need to fit data where the data points are not equally distributed. However, the fit uses a convolution. From my understanding for the convolution to work, the arrays need to have the same spacing. For that I need to interpolate the data (Is that true?). But now, I fit the interpolated data, and anywhere where I only have few data points, the interpolation gives more datapoints, hence these regions will have an influence on the fit, that is overweighted.
Specifically, I want to fit time resolved absorption data, that have an exponential distribution of data points. I work with python.
Current idea of solving: With python curve_fit, I can give weights, so to counterbalance the overweighing by interpolation. Not exactly sure, how to do that, but I guess it should work.
I just wonder, since this should not be an uncommon issue, if anyone knows the appropriate way to solve.
EDIT:
I can't include my problem beacause this will be a huge amount of code. Down below is a simple example: A linear function. So also the fit function does not include a convolution. The first half of the x-values has a bigger spacing than the second half. Then I do a 'normal' fit, a fit after interpolation and a fit after interpolation with weights.
My attempt to use weights: The idea is to weigh down all points where the density of points is too high. So if there is originally only 1 point, but from interpolation now there are 10, these points get a sigma=1/(1/10)=10. So basically sigma=interpolation_stepsize/x_stepsize.
Ideally, it should reproduce the fit without interpolation. It doesnt and from my approach it is clear that it wont, but I dont have better ideas.
Results: The attempts with weights is not always closer to the 'normal' fit, but the errors are on the same order of magnitude, whereas the fit with only interpolation gives erros that are too small (which is no surprise, due to the closed-by added datapoints by interpolation)
As a reminder: for my problem I need a convolution, hence the need for interpolation (in the given example it is basically nonsense, but used for illustration).
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def interpolate_data(x_data, y_data, stepsize=0.5):
    """
    Interpolates given data and returns interpolated values at x-steps of 0.5.

    Parameters:
    - x_data: Array of x values (sorted in ascending order).
    - y_data: Array of corresponding y values.

    Returns:
    - Interpolated x values at steps of stepsize.
    - Interpolated y values at corresponding x values.
    """
    # Define the target x values with steps of stepsize
    x_interp = np.arange(np.min(x_data), np.max(x_data) + stepsize, stepsize)

    # Interpolate y values corresponding to the x_interp values
    y_interp = np.interp(x_interp, x_data, y_data)

    return x_interp, y_interp

def linear(x,a,b):
    return a*x+b

################################## Generate data ###############################################
noise_amplitude = 10
# Parameters for the linear function
a = 3.5
b = 2.0
# Define step sizes
x_step1 = 1
x_step2 = 0.1
# Length of each half
half_length = 10
# First half with step size x_step1
x_first_half = np.arange(0, half_length, x_step1)
# Second half with step size x_step2
x_second_half = np.arange(half_length, 2*half_length, x_step2)
# Combine both halves
x = np.concatenate((x_first_half, x_second_half))
# print("Generated x array:")
# print(x)

# Generate y values without noise
y_true = linear(x, a, b)
# Add normally distributed noise to y values
noise = np.random.normal(0, noise_amplitude, size=x.size)
y_data = y_true + noise

interpolation_stepsize = x_step2
x_ip, y_ip =interpolate_data(x,y_data,stepsize=interpolation_stepsize)
########################################## Fit ############################################
%matplotlib inline
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
###################################### No interpolation ###############################
popt, pcov = curve_fit(linear, x, y_data)
# Extract the fitted parameters and their errors (standard deviations)
a_fit, b_fit = popt
std_err_a, std_err_b = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
# Print the fitted parameters and their errors 
print(f"Fitted parameters (No interpolation):")
print(f"  a = {a_fit:.3f} ± {std_err_a:.3f}")
print(f"  b = {b_fit:.3f} ± {std_err_b:.3f}")
###################################### With interpolation ###############################
# Perform curve fitting using curve_fit
popt_ip, pcov_ip = curve_fit(linear, x_ip, y_ip)
# Extract the fitted parameters and their errors (standard deviations)
a_fit, b_fit = popt_ip
std_err_a, std_err_b = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov_ip))
# print the fitted parameters and their errors
print(f"Fitted parameters (With interpolation):")
print(f"  a = {a_fit:.3f} ± {std_err_a:.3f}")
print(f"  b = {b_fit:.3f} ± {std_err_b:.3f}")
###################################### With interpolation and     weights ###############################
# Attempt 1: weigh down / weigh up by the factor interpolation_stepsize/x_region. So that regions that have to many points 
# due to interpolation have less weight and vice versa.
## Construct weight array
# First half with step size x_step1
w_first_half = np.ones(int(len(x_ip)/2))*interpolation_stepsize/x_step1
# Second half with step size x_step2
w_second_half =     np.ones(int(len(x_ip)/2))*interpolation_stepsize/x_step2
# Combine both halves
weigth_array = np.concatenate((w_first_half,w_second_half))
###############################################
# Perform curve fitting using curve_fit
popt_ip_weighted, pcov_ip_weighted = curve_fit(linear, x_ip, y_ip,sigma=1/weigth_array)

# Extract the fitted parameters and their errors (standard deviations)
a_fit, b_fit = popt_ip_weighted
std_err_a, std_err_b = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov_ip_weighted))

# Print the fitted parameters and their errors
print(f"Fitted parameters (With interpolation and weights):")
print(f"  a = {a_fit:.3f} ± {std_err_a:.3f}")
print(f"  b = {b_fit:.3f} ± {std_err_b:.3f}")

################################ Plot the data and the fitted models ######################################


plt.scatter(x, y_data, label='Data with noise')
plt.scatter(x_ip, y_ip, marker="x", s=10,label='Interpolated Data with noise')

plt.plot(x, y_true, color='k', linestyle='--', label='True linear model')
plt.plot(x, linear(x, *popt), color='green', label='Fitted linear model')
plt.plot(x_ip, linear(x_ip, *popt_ip), color='red', label='Fitted linear model of interpolated data')
plt.plot(x_ip, linear(x_ip, *popt_ip_weighted), color='blue', label='Fitted linear model of weighted interpolated data')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Curve fitting with linear model')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

Example output should be like:
Fitted parameters (No interpolation):
  a = 3.164 ± 0.232
  b = 6.627 ± 3.382
Fitted parameters (With interpolation):
  a = 2.873 ± 0.136
  b = 9.113 ± 1.566
Fitted parameters (With interpolation and weights):
  a = 3.279 ± 0.222
  b = 5.053 ± 3.364



Welcome to SO, we need at least a dataset, expected input and output. A [mcve] is the best way to start, also read [ask]. Update your post accordingly with data, code you have tried, issue you are facing.

The data set in THAT plot is clearly linear, not exponential.  Has this been artificially weighted?

Maybe that title is clearer? I care about the x-values being exponentially distributed. And since my main problem invovles unhandy data and huge amounts of code snippets, I thought this example breaks it down.

Maybe, as the convolution is the main issue, you should explain that  bit more. Also, you might rescale x on log and change the fitfunction accordingly. Is that an option?
